# vglm() function from package VGAM VS the multinom() function from package nnet

Tags: r, regression, logistic, multinomial-distribution

I'am trying to do a multinomial logistic regression to explain the political orientations in Tunisia but I'am really confused about using the vglm() function from package VGAM or the multinom() function from package nnet or the mlogit function... can someone tell me please the difference and wich one is the best?

Comment: VGAM is a large and complex package, so for a start you should see multinom() from nnet can do your job, that should be simpler to use.  I don't know about mlogit() function.  If you want more specific advice, you should tell us with more details what you want to do.